# Can a label and a count link to the same detail list?

Tags: usability, hyperlinks

We have a page with links to different lists and we are debating what the clickable link should be.  What is the best option?

1. The label and the count are both links to the same list.  Is it confusing to have two links to the same list?
2. Only the label is the link.
3. Only the number is the link. Is the number, especially if it is 1, a large enough clickable area?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It seems like current convention is to make the entire line a link, like so:

[image: List of links with names and values]
.

This is especially useful for touch screen users as the effective clickable/touchable area is greatly increased.

As Drew mentioned, the entire row is also hoverable, so the functionality is easily discoverable and you can reduce the usage of the legacy blue underline link appearance.

Comment: This solves another problem with the original list, where the wide gap between the numbers and labels makes it hard to associate them with each other. Alternatively, you can bring them together like this: "Not scheduled (1)". And in that case it seems natural to link just the label.

Answer (score 2):

I think that both linked, as you have above, is confusing. Users will wonder what the difference is between the two links.

Of your options I think 2 (only the label is the link) is the best.

But you do have a few other options that are worth looking into:

1) Both are links but only the label looks like a link. This way you don't punish people who click the wrong place.

2) Only the label looks like a link but the whole row is your click and hover area. When a user hovers over any part of the row, the hover state of the link is activated and clicking anywhere on the row triggers the link.

I like my #2 above the best.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the approach of keeping the entire row as clickable to drill down to details (as mentioned by Drew and Ross). However if you intend to use it on touch based devices you may not be able to achieve a hover but it will be most intuitive (infact the only option for the user to view details)

Also if it is a need of your system to follow the conventional link appearance, I would suggest keeping the count as link. The simple reason being, when you click on a text/name you may be inclined to expect the details of that text.
Eg. "Activities with interpreter needed" may for a split second give you a question 'what does it mean' meanwhile "2" will implicitly hint to how many and that will drive the next question which are they.

Using links both on the label and the count should be avoided as it will create an expectation that both will give different results. Since it leads to the same result there seems no use of leaving redundant links.

My vote still goes to keeping the whole row clickable for viewing the details.